# What are the differences between IEnumerable and Lists when using projections?

Tags: c#, linq, copy, iteration

I've noticed that there are some seemingly strange differences concerning IEnumerable and Lists when it comes to object copies.

What I did:

A: IEnumerable through projection using deep copy constructors

B: List through projection using deep copy constructors

In the following example why is it, that in the case of IEnumerables I seem to still have access to the original object, even though my constructors are deep copies?

Program output:

Hello World!

weird result: 023

sane result: 123

Press any key to continue . . .

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

            Foo f1 = new Foo(1);
            Foo f2 = new Foo(2);
            Foo f3 = new Foo(3);
            List<Foo> foos = new List<Foo> { f1, f2, f3 };

            IEnumerable<Tuple<Foo, Bar>> tuplesWeird = foos.Select(x => new Tuple<Foo, Bar>(x, new Bar(x.m_bar)));
            List<Tuple<Foo, Bar>> tuplesSane = foos.Select(x => new Tuple<Foo, Bar>(x, new Bar(x.m_bar))).ToList();

            f1.m_bar.m_value = 0;

            Console.WriteLine("weird result: "+tuplesWeird.Select(x => x.Item2.ToString()).Aggregate((x,y) => x + y ));
            Console.WriteLine("sane result: " + tuplesSane.Select(x => x.Item2.ToString()).Aggregate((x, y) => x + y));
        }


        private class Foo
        {
            public Bar m_bar;
            public Foo(int i)
            {
                m_bar = new Bar(i);
            }

            public override string ToString()
            {
                return m_bar.ToString();
            }
        }

        private class Bar
        {
            public int m_value;
            public Bar(int value)
            {
                m_value = value;
            }

            public Bar(Bar bar)
            {
                m_value = bar.m_value;
            }

            public override string ToString()
            {
                return m_value.ToString();
            }
        }
    }       
}
```

Comment: Different time of executing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's about when the `IEnumerable` is enumerated. `tuplesWeird` isn't enumerated until you call the print method - i.e. after the value in `f1` has been changed whereas `tuplesSane` is enumerated when you call the `ToList()` method.